# "OnCertificateError" event is NOT fired for resource requests

Tags: ssl, cefsharp

I have come across a scenario where "OnCertificateError" event is NOT fired for resource requests originated via XHR or FETCH request. My question is - Is OnCertificateError fires only for main frame requests or it is supporsed to fire for all SSL/TLS errors?

I have also tried adding a Cef Command Line Argument to enable errors so that I can catch them under "OnCertificateError" event but it just does not work.

Answer (score 0):

> it is supporsed to fire for all SSL/TLS errors?

No. What you are seeing is the expected behaviour. Sub-resource requests are blocked without ever calling `OnCertificateError`. If you look at the CEF source you will see the following

```cpp
if (!is_main_frame_request) {
    // A sub-resource has a certificate error. The user doesn't really
    // have a context for making the right decision, so block the request
    // hard.
    std::move(callback).Run(content::CERTIFICATE_REQUEST_RESULT_TYPE_DENY);
    return base::NullCallback();
  }
```

https://github.com/chromiumembedded/cef/blob/e4acacee18d66d9bfe65a15072307d619117bd32/libcef/browser/certificate_query.cc#L94